# swapExactETHForTokens function execution

Tags: web3.py, python, error, pancakeswap, binance

Please, help me. I try to do `swapExactETHForTokens` function from PancakeSwap Router contract. It's my code:

```
def swap_exact_eth(router_contract_sample,
                   token_contract,
                   amount_out_min,
                   path,
                   to,
                   deadline,
                   gas,
                   gas_price,
                   nonce):

    approve_value = allowance_function(token_contract, router_contract_sample)
    print('approve_value: ', approve_value)
    estimate_gas = router_contract_sample.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        amount_out_min,
        path,
        to,
        deadline
    ).estimateGas({'value': approve_value})
    print('estimate_gas for swap: ', estimate_gas)
    swap_builder = router_contract_sample.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
        amount_out_min,
        path,
        to,
        deadline
    ).buildTransaction(
        {
            'nonce': nonce,
            'gas': gas,
            'gasPrice': gas_price,
            'value': approve_value
        }
    )

    tx_hash, tx_status = get_tx_details(swap_builder)
    return tx_hash, tx_status

router_contract = contract
main_token_contract = get_contract_instance(
    token_name='Tether USD',
    token_symbol='USDT',
    token_address=w3.toChecksumAddress('0x7ef95a0FEE0Dd31b22626fA2e10Ee6A223F8a684')
)

# nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(bot_address)

# Создаем экземпляр контракта weth (wbnb)
wbnb_token_contract = get_contract_instance(
    token_name='Wrapped BNB',
    token_symbol='WBNB',
    token_address=w3.toChecksumAddress('0xae13d989daC2f0dEbFf460aC112a837C89BAa7cd')
)


# getAmountsOut
get_amounts_out = contract.functions.getAmountsOut(
    1000000000000000000,
    [wbnb_token_contract.address, main_token_contract.address]
).call()
print('wbnb need amount: ', get_amounts_out[0])
print('usdt need amount: ', get_amounts_out[1])


# approve из контракта wbnb
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(bot_address)
approve_tx_hash, approve_tx_status = approve_function(
    token_contract=wbnb_token_contract,
    router_address=router_contract.address,
    approve_value=get_amounts_out[0],
    nonce=nonce
)
print('approve tx hash: ', approve_tx_hash)
print('approve_tx_status: ', approve_tx_status)

## approve из контракта токена
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(bot_address)

approve_tx_hash, approve_tx_status = approve_function(
    token_contract=main_token_contract,
    router_address=router_contract.address,
    approve_value=get_amounts_out[1],
    nonce=nonce
)
print('approve tx hash: ', approve_tx_hash)
print('approve_tx_status: ', approve_tx_status)


# test swap exact eth
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(bot_address)
gas_price = value_based_gas_price_strategy(value)
swap_tx_hash, swap_tx_status = swap_exact_eth(
    router_contract_sample=router_contract,
    token_contract=main_token_contract,
    amount_out_min=get_amounts_out[1],
    path=[wbnb_token_contract.address, main_token_contract.address],
    to=bot_address,
    deadline=w3.eth.getBlock('latest')['timestamp'] + 1000000000,
    gas=gas,
    gas_price=gas_price + 10,
    nonce=nonce
)
```

I receive this error:

```
raise ContractLogicError(response['error']['message'])
web3.exceptions.ContractLogicError: execution reverted: PancakeRouter: INSUFFICIENT_OUTPUT_AMOUNT
```

I calculate exact amounts of output tokens via `getAmountsOut` function, but it does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a swap, you're likely to get a little less than the expected amount ( if other people sell/buy while your tx is being processed the price will be different that the one calculated by  `getAmountsOut()`, that's called slippage, you probably already heard the word). If you're doing this as a test project i suggest setting minAmountOut to 0, if you're going to use this to actually sell/buy big amount of tokens, id calculate an acceptable slippage (maybe 1 or 2%) percentage and i'll use this